# Sparksql filtering (selecting with where clause) with multiple conditions

Tags: python, sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

Hi I have the following issue:

```
numeric.registerTempTable("numeric").
```

All the values that I want to filter on are literal null strings and not N/A or Null values.

I tried these three options:

1. `numeric_filtered = numeric.filter(numeric['LOW'] != 'null').filter(numeric['HIGH'] != 'null').filter(numeric['NORMAL'] != 'null')`
2. `numeric_filtered = numeric.filter(numeric['LOW'] != 'null' AND numeric['HIGH'] != 'null' AND numeric['NORMAL'] != 'null')`
3. `sqlContext.sql("SELECT * from numeric WHERE LOW != 'null' AND HIGH != 'null' AND NORMAL != 'null'")`

Unfortunately, numeric_filtered is always empty. I checked and numeric has data that should be filtered based on these conditions.

Here are some sample values:

Low          High          Normal

3.5           5.0           null

2.0           14.0          null

null          38.0          null

null          null          null

1.0           null          4.0

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Your are using logical conjunction (AND). It means that all columns have to be different than `'null'` for row to be included. Lets illustrate that using `filter` version as an example:

```
numeric = sqlContext.createDataFrame([
    ('3.5,', '5.0', 'null'), ('2.0', '14.0', 'null'),  ('null', '38.0', 'null'),
    ('null', 'null', 'null'),  ('1.0', 'null', '4.0')],
    ('low', 'high', 'normal'))

numeric_filtered_1 = numeric.where(numeric['LOW'] != 'null')
numeric_filtered_1.show()

## +----+----+------+
## | low|high|normal|
## +----+----+------+
## |3.5,| 5.0|  null|
## | 2.0|14.0|  null|
## | 1.0|null|   4.0|
## +----+----+------+

numeric_filtered_2 = numeric_filtered_1.where(
    numeric_filtered_1['NORMAL'] != 'null')
numeric_filtered_2.show()

## +---+----+------+
## |low|high|normal|
## +---+----+------+
## |1.0|null|   4.0|
## +---+----+------+

numeric_filtered_3 = numeric_filtered_2.where(
    numeric_filtered_2['HIGH'] != 'null')
numeric_filtered_3.show()

## +---+----+------+
## |low|high|normal|
## +---+----+------+
## +---+----+------+
```

All remaining methods you've tried follow exactly the same schema. What you need here is a logical disjunction (OR).

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col 

numeric_filtered = df.where(
    (col('LOW')    != 'null') | 
    (col('NORMAL') != 'null') |
    (col('HIGH')   != 'null'))
numeric_filtered.show()

## +----+----+------+
## | low|high|normal|
## +----+----+------+
## |3.5,| 5.0|  null|
## | 2.0|14.0|  null|
## |null|38.0|  null|
## | 1.0|null|   4.0|
## +----+----+------+
```

or with raw SQL:

```
numeric.registerTempTable("numeric")
sqlContext.sql("""SELECT * FROM numeric
    WHERE low != 'null' OR normal != 'null' OR high != 'null'"""
).show()

## +----+----+------+
## | low|high|normal|
## +----+----+------+
## |3.5,| 5.0|  null|
## | 2.0|14.0|  null|
## |null|38.0|  null|
## | 1.0|null|   4.0|
## +----+----+------+
```

See also: [Pyspark: multiple conditions in when clause](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37707305)

Comment: Thanks! That helped a lot. The important thing is to enclose the individual conditions in parantheses **(** col('foo') == 'bar' **)**

Answer (score 0):

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, countDistinct 
totalrecordcount = df.where("ColumnName is not null").select(countDistinct("ColumnName")).collect()[0][0]
```

Comment: Welcome to the community. please consider editing your answer in order to explain how your code helps to fix the current issue.