# multiple conditions for filter in spark data frames

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a data frame with four fields. one of the field name is Status and i am trying to use a OR condition in .filter for a dataframe . I tried below queries but no luck.

```
df2 = df1.filter(("Status=2") || ("Status =3"))

df2 = df1.filter("Status=2" || "Status =3")
```

Has anyone used this before. I have seen a similar question on stack overflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33747834/sparksql-filtering-selecting-with-where-clause-with-multiple-conditions) . They have used below code for using OR condition. But that code is for pyspark.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col 

numeric_filtered = df.where(
(col('LOW')    != 'null') | 
(col('NORMAL') != 'null') |
(col('HIGH')   != 'null'))
numeric_filtered.show()
```

Comment: Judging by this line: `scala> from pyspark.sql.column import Column` it seems like you're trying to use pyspark code when you're actually using scala

Comment: @TonTorres Yes it was a mistake i realized that after posting this question. making that edit now.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Instead of:

```
df2 = df1.filter("Status=2" || "Status =3")
```

Try:

```
df2 = df1.filter($"Status" === 2 || $"Status" === 3)
```

Comment: The opposite of `===` is `=!=`

Comment: Depends on version -- for pre-2.0, use `!==` but after version 2.0.0 `!==` does not have the same precedence as `===`, use `=!=` instead

Comment: How to filter  DF on multiple columns in Java. I have something like this `df.filter(df.col("name").equalTo("john"))`. I want to filter on multiple columns in a single line?

Comment: You can just add another .filter after your current one. df.filter(df.col("name").equalTo("john")).filter(df.col("name").equalTo("tim"))

Comment: @DavidSchuler Do those chained filters get merged into a single worker stage in the Spark Analyzer?

Comment: @DavidGriffin how to add "is null" condition with OR(||) here?

Answer (score 22):

This question has been answered but for future reference, I would like to mention that, in the context of this question, the `where` and `filter` methods in Dataset/Dataframe supports two syntaxes:
The SQL string parameters:

```
df2 = df1.filter(("Status = 2 or Status = 3"))
```

and Col based parameters (mentioned by [@David](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35882046/4670887) ):

```
df2 = df1.filter($"Status" === 2 || $"Status" === 3)
```

It seems the OP'd combined these two syntaxes. 
Personally, I prefer the first syntax because it's cleaner and more generic.

Answer (score 4):

In spark/scala, it's pretty easy to filter with varargs.

```
val d = spark.read...//data contains column named matid
val ids = Seq("BNBEL0608AH", "BNBEL00608H")
val filtered = d.filter($"matid".isin(ids:_*))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
df2 = df1.filter("Status = 2 OR Status = 3")
```

Worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can try, (filtering with 1 object like a list or a set of values)

```
ds = ds.filter(functions.col(COL_NAME).isin(myList));
```

or as @Tony Fraser suggested, you can try, (with a Seq of objects)

```
ds = ds.filter(functions.col(COL_NAME).isin(mySeq));
```

All the answers are correct but most of them do not represent a good coding style. Also, you should always consider the variable length of arguments for the future, even though they are static at a certain point in time.

Comment: I think you need to write as `myList:_*` to convert to varargs, or use `isInCollection`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use filter

```
package dataframe

import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
/**
 * @author vaquar.khan@gmail.com
 */
//

object DataFrameExample{
  //
  case class Employee(id: Integer, name: String, address: String, salary: Double, state: String,zip:Integer)
  //
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val spark =
      SparkSession.builder()
        .appName("DataFrame-Basic")
        .master("local[4]")
        .getOrCreate()

    import spark.implicits._

    // create a sequence of case class objects 

    // (we defined the case class above)

    val emp = Seq( 
    Employee(1, "vaquar khan", "111 algoinquin road chicago", 120000.00, "AZ",60173),
    Employee(2, "Firdos Pasha", "1300 algoinquin road chicago", 2500000.00, "IL",50112),
    Employee(3, "Zidan khan", "112 apt abcd timesqure NY", 50000.00, "NY",55490),
    Employee(4, "Anwars khan", "washington dc", 120000.00, "VA",33245),
    Employee(5, "Deepak sharma ", "rolling edows schumburg", 990090.00, "IL",60172),
    Employee(6, "afaq khan", "saeed colony Bhopal", 1000000.00, "AZ",60173)
    )

    val employee=spark.sparkContext.parallelize(emp, 4).toDF()

     employee.printSchema()

    employee.show()


    employee.select("state", "zip").show()

    println("*** use filter() to choose rows")

    employee.filter($"state".equalTo("IL")).show()

    println("*** multi contidtion in filer || ")

    employee.filter($"state".equalTo("IL") || $"state".equalTo("AZ")).show()

    println("*** multi contidtion in filer &&  ")

    employee.filter($"state".equalTo("AZ") && $"zip".equalTo("60173")).show()

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In java spark dataset it can be used as

> Dataset userfilter =
> user.filter(col("gender").isin("male","female"));

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use function expr with where clause

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.expr

df2 = df1.where(expr("col1 = 'value1' and col2 = 'value2'"))
```

It works the same.

Answer (score 1):

For future references : 
we can use **`isInCollection`** to filter ,here is a example :
Note : It will look for **exact match**

```
  def getSelectedTablesRows(allTablesInfoDF: DataFrame, tableNames: Seq[String]): DataFrame = {

    allTablesInfoDF.where(col("table_name").isInCollection(tableNames))

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

If we want **partial match** just like **contains**, we can chain the contain call like this :

```
def getSelectedTablesRows2(allTablesInfoDF: DataFrame, tableNames: Seq[String]): DataFrame = {

    val tableFilters = tableNames.map(_.toLowerCase()).map(name => lower(col("table_name")).contains(name))
    val finalFilter = tableFilters.fold(lit(false))((accu, newTableFilter) => accu or newTableFilter)
    allTablesInfoDF.where(finalFilter)

  }
```

Answer (score -3):

```
df2 = df1.filter("Status=2")
     .filter("Status=3");
```

Comment: this is a AND filter not a OR

Comment: This condition first filters the dataset where Status=2 and then filters the resulting dataset   where Status=3, and hence it is AND condition and not OR