# Pass filters as parameter to Dataframe.filter function

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I have a Dataframe `userdf` as

`val userdf = sparkSession.read.json(sparkContext.parallelize(Array("""[{"id" : 1,"name" : "user1"},{"id" : 2,"name" : "user2"}]"""))`)

```
scala> userdf.show
+---+-----+
| id| name|
+---+-----+
|  1|user1|
|  2|user2|
+---+-----+
```

I want to retrieve user with `id === 1` and same I can achieve using code like

```
scala> userdf.filter($"id"===1).show
+---+-----+
| id| name|
+---+-----+
|  1|user1|
+---+-----+
```

What I want to achieve is like

```
val filter1 = $"id"===1
userdf.filter(filter1).show
```

These filters are fetch from configuration files and I am trying to achieve a more complex query using this building block, something like

```
userdf.filter(filter1 OR filter2).filter(filter3).show
```

where `filter1`, `filter2`, `filter3`, `AND` and `OR` condition are fetched from configurations

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `filter` method can also accept a string that it a sql expression.
this code should produce the same result

```
userdf.filter("id = 1").show
```

so you can just get that string from config

Comment: this solution will not work with multiple "and" and "or" condition. ie,  userdf.filter($"name"==="user1" || $"id" === 1) works fine, but userdf.filter("id=2" || "id=1") is not working.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35881152/multiple-conditions-for-filter-in-spark-data-frames

Comment: as long as it is a valid sql statement it should work: `userdf.filter("id=2 or id=1")`

Comment: thanks. the statement "as long as it is a valid sql statement" is very helpful.

Comment: @user811602 any luck on resolving this issue?

Comment: @JellfLL I have created valid sql string statement as commented by lev.