# Multiple AND conditions on the same column in pyspark without join operation

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a table of three columns `[s,p,o]`. I would like to remove rows, that for each entry in s , the p column does not include `[P625, P36]` values both.  For example

```
+----+----+------
|   s|   p|  o  |
+----+----+-----|
| Q31| P36| Q239|
| Q31|P625|   51|
| Q45| P36| Q597|
| Q45|P625|  123|
| Q51|P625|   22|
| Q24|P625|   56|
```

The end result should be

```
+----+----+------
|   s|   p|  o  |
+----+----+-----|
| Q31| P36| Q239|
| Q31|P625|   51|
| Q45| P36| Q597|
| Q45|P625|  123|
```

Using join operation, the above task is easy.

```
df.filter(df.p=='P625').join(df.filter(df.p=='P36'),'s')
```

But is there a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: I haven't used this technology, but you may see if it will allow you to do df.filter(df.p=='P265' || df.p=='P36') and you may find something here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35882046/2793683

Comment: @pault and dmoore1181 both suggested queries won't remove the last three rows of the original table in the given example.

Comment: It is is not duplicate, I am not conditioning on different columns of the same row

Comment: @user1848018 I see what you mean now. I think you have to do a join in this case. There may be other ways, but the join is likely most efficient.

Comment: That `join()` will not end up with your end result example either. I think you're likely going to have to turn `p` and `o` into a single column `struct()`, then do `.groupBy()`, `.agg()`, `.filter()`, then `.flatMap()` to get your end result example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a window

```
from pyspark.sql import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

winSpec = Window.partitionBy('s')
df.withColumn("s_list", collect_list("s").over(winSpec)).
filter(array_contains(col("s_list"), "P625") & array_contains(col("s_list"), "P36") & size(col("s_list")) = 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Forgive me, as I'm much more familiar with the Scala API, but perhaps you can easily convert it:

```
scala> val df = spark.createDataset(Seq(
     |      ("Q31", "P36", "Q239"),
     |      ("Q31", "P625", "51"),
     |      ("Q45", "P36", "Q597"),
     |      ("Q45", "P625", "123"),
     |      ("Q51", "P625", "22"),
     |      ("Q24", "P625", "56")
     | )).toDF("s", "p", "o")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [s: string, p: string ... 1 more field]

scala> (df.select($"s", struct($"p", $"o").as("po"))
     |   .groupBy("s")
     |   .agg(collect_list($"po").as("polist"))
     |   .as[(String, Array[(String, String)])]
     |   .flatMap(r => {
     |     val ps = r._2.map(_._1).toSet
     |           if(ps("P625") && ps("P36")) {
     |             r._2.flatMap(po => Some(r._1, po._1, po._2))
     |           } else {
     |             None
     |           }
     |   }).toDF("s", "p", "o")
     |   .show())
+---+----+----+                                                                 
|  s|   p|   o|
+---+----+----+
|Q31| P36|Q239|
|Q31|P625|  51|
|Q45| P36|Q597|
|Q45|P625| 123|
+---+----+----+
```

For reference, your `join()` command above would have returned:

```
scala> df.filter($"p" === "P625").join(df.filter($"p" === "P36"), "s").show
+---+----+---+---+----+
|  s|   p|  o|  p|   o|
+---+----+---+---+----+
|Q31|P625| 51|P36|Q239|
|Q45|P625|123|P36|Q597|
+---+----+---+---+----+
```

Which can be worked into your final solution as well, perhaps with less code, but I'm not sure which method would be more efficient, as that's largely data dependent.