# What is the best way to filter many columns together in Spark dataframe?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

A sample data:

```
+--------------------+-----+--------+----+----------+--------+-----------+
|                  id|click|    hour|  C1|banner_pos| site_id|site_domain|
+--------------------+-----+--------+----+----------+--------+-----------+
| NULL               |    0|14102100|1005|         0|1fbe01fe|   f3845767|
|10000169349117863715|    0|14102100|1005|         0|1fbe01fe|   f3845767|
|10000371904215119486|    0|NULL    |1005|         0|1fbe01fe|   f3845767|
|10000640724480838376|    0|14102100|1005|         0|1fbe01fe|   f3845767|
|10000679056417042096|    0|14102100|1005|         1|fe8cc448|   9166c161|
+--------------------+-----+--------+----+----------+--------+-----------+
```

Expected result:

```
+--------------------+-----+--------+----+----------+--------+-----------+
|                  id|click|    hour|  C1|banner_pos| site_id|site_domain|
+--------------------+-----+--------+----+----------+--------+-----------+
| NULL               |    0|14102100|1005|         0|1fbe01fe|   f3845767|
|10000371904215119486|    0|NULL    |1005|         0|1fbe01fe|   f3845767|
+--------------------+-----+--------+----+----------+--------+-----------+
```

I want to filter all columns in a Dataframe with the condition that at least one column contains "NULL" string. I have many columns, around 30. 
I have seen that with a few columns conditions can be added like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35881152/multiple-conditions-for-filter-in-spark-data-frames/46375927):

```
df2 = df1.filter($"Status" === 2 || $"Status" === 3)
```

But since I have many columns with the same conditions, is there a way to treat the `columns` as a collection and filter them all together?
I have tried the following but it doesn't seem to work:

```
  df2.filter(
    lit(
      df2.columns.map(col(_).contains("NULL")).contains(lit(true))
    )
  ).show()
```

It seems `df2.columns.map(col(_).contains("NULL")).contains(lit(true))` always returns `false`.

**Why is it like this? Could you explain why this doesn't work?**

---

The following codes work for the above purpose.

```
  df.filter(
    lit(true).isin(df.columns.map(col(_).contains("NULL")): _*)
  ).show()
```

Comment: It would be very helpful to provide a sample dataset and the desired output

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is your first snippet

```
df.columns.map(col(_).contains("NULL"))
```

returns an

```
Array[Column]
```

and you try to pass that entire array to search for the boolean literal "true" with this statement

```
df2.columns.map(col(_).contains("NULL")).contains(lit(true))
```

Since it is a complex structure of an `Array[Column]` it does not work.

But this following expression:

```
df.columns.map(col(_).contains("NULL")): _*
```

sends each of the array element as a single argument one my one to the `isin` function, and thus your filter works.

Hope this could explain!

Answer (score 0):

```
df.filter(r=> r.toSeq.exists(c => c == null))
```

Comment: Explain why this code works & what it actually does.