# Scala filter multiple condition

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

How do I perform a DataFrame select for Distance greater than or equal to 50 AND a Treatment_Type of 1 or 2? My code below seems not to like the multiple condition &&/and in the filter statement.

```
df.select("Distance", "Treatment_Type").filter("Distance >= 50").filter("Treatment_Type == 1" && "Treatment_Type == 2").show
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mentioned Treatment_Type as 1 or 2 but your code has it as &&. Please use || and let us know.

Comment: you can use this: `df.select("Distance", "Treatment_Type").filter(df.col("Distance") >= 50 && df.col("Treatment_Type") == 1 && df.col("Treatment_Type") == 2).show()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [multiple conditions for filter in spark data frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35881152/multiple-conditions-for-filter-in-spark-data-frames)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want `OR` condition but you gave the condition for the `Treatment_Type` 1 `AND` 2. So, you should give the correct `OR` condition. Here is an example dataframe

```
+---+--------+--------------+
| id|Distance|Treatment_Type|
+---+--------+--------------+
|  1|      40|             1|
|  2|      40|             2|
|  3|      40|             3|
|  4|      50|             1|
|  5|      50|             2|
|  6|      50|             3|
|  7|      60|             1|
|  8|      60|             2|
+---+--------+--------------+
```

Under the below conditions, it give the same results as follows:

```
df.select("Distance", "Treatment_Type").filter(col("Distance") >= 50 && (col("Treatment_Type") === 1 || col("Treatment_Type") === 2))
df.select("Distance", "Treatment_Type").filter(col("Distance") >= 50 && col("Treatment_Type").isin(1,2))
df.select("Distance", "Treatment_Type").where("Distance >= 50 and Treatment_Type in (1, 2)").show()

+--------+--------------+
|Distance|Treatment_Type|
+--------+--------------+
|      50|             1|
|      50|             2|
|      60|             1|
|      60|             2|
+--------+--------------+
```