# PySpark: multiple conditions in when clause

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I would like to modify the cell values of a dataframe column (Age) where currently it is blank and I would only do it if another column (Survived) has the value 0  for the corresponding row where it is blank for Age. If it is 1 in the Survived column but blank in Age column then I will keep it as null.

I tried to use `&&` operator but it didn't work. Here is my code:

```
tdata.withColumn("Age",  when((tdata.Age == "" && tdata.Survived == "0"), mean_age_0).otherwise(tdata.Age)).show()
```

Any suggestions how to handle that? Thanks.

Error Message:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
  File "<ipython-input-33-3e691784411c>", line 1
    tdata.withColumn("Age",  when((tdata.Age == "" && tdata.Survived == "0"), mean_age_0).otherwise(tdata.Age)).show()
                                                    ^
```

Answer (score 149, accepted):

You get `SyntaxError` error exception because Python has no `&&` operator. It has `and` and `&` where the latter one is the correct choice to create   boolean expressions on `Column` (`|` for a logical disjunction and `~` for logical negation).

Condition you created is also invalid because it doesn't consider [operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence). `&` in Python has a higher precedence than `==` so expression has to be parenthesized.

```
(col("Age") == "") & (col("Survived") == "0")
## Column<b'((Age = ) AND (Survived = 0))'>
```

On a side note `when` function is equivalent to `case` expression not `WHEN` clause. Still the same rules apply. Conjunction:

```
df.where((col("foo") > 0) & (col("bar") < 0))
```

Disjunction:

```
df.where((col("foo") > 0) | (col("bar") < 0))
```

You can of course define conditions separately to avoid brackets:

```
cond1 = col("Age") == "" 
cond2 = col("Survived") == "0"

cond1 & cond2
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment about the operator precedence, it solved my issue with getting a date range

Comment: It works! But is the use of boolean expressions (in `where`, `filter`, etc.) documented in Spark?

Comment: "Condition you created is also invalid because it doesn't consider operator precedence. & in Python has a higher precedence than == so expression has to be parenthesized."
Very helpful observation

Answer (score 37):

**when** in **pyspark** multiple conditions can be built using **&**(for and) and **|** (for or).

Note:In **pyspark** t is important to enclose every expressions within parenthesis () that combine to form the condition

```
%pyspark
dataDF = spark.createDataFrame([(66, "a", "4"), 
                                (67, "a", "0"), 
                                (70, "b", "4"), 
                                (71, "d", "4")],
                                ("id", "code", "amt"))
dataDF.withColumn("new_column",
       when((col("code") == "a") | (col("code") == "d"), "A")
      .when((col("code") == "b") & (col("amt") == "4"), "B")
      .otherwise("A1")).show()
```

In Spark Scala code (**&&**) or (**||**) conditions can be used within **when** function

```
//scala
val dataDF = Seq(
      (66, "a", "4"), (67, "a", "0"), (70, "b", "4"), (71, "d", "4"
      )).toDF("id", "code", "amt")
dataDF.withColumn("new_column",
       when(col("code") === "a" || col("code") === "d", "A")
      .when(col("code") === "b" && col("amt") === "4", "B")
      .otherwise("A1")).show()
```

=======================

```
Output:
+---+----+---+----------+
| id|code|amt|new_column|
+---+----+---+----------+
| 66|   a|  4|         A|
| 67|   a|  0|         A|
| 70|   b|  4|         B|
| 71|   d|  4|         A|
+---+----+---+----------+
```

This code snippet is copied from [sparkbyexamples.com](https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark-when-otherwise-example/)

Answer (score 4):

it should works at least in pyspark 2.4

```
tdata = tdata.withColumn("Age",  when((tdata.Age == "") & (tdata.Survived == "0") , "NewValue").otherwise(tdata.Age))
```

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure the order of the conditions also matter.

RIGHT : Restrictive condition is after the relaxed codition.

```
ultimate_optimized_join = spark_filteredfinal_df1.crossJoin(spark_filteredfinal_df2) \
                        .where( (F.col("df1_sorted_row_num") < F.col("df2_sorted_row_num"))                                                          
                                &
                                (F.col("df1_a_x_dup") == F.col("df2_a_x_dup"))
                                ) \
                        .select(["df1_a_x_dup", "df2_a_x_dup", "df1_sorted_row_num", "df1_sorted_row_num",  "df1_collectedIds", "df2_collectedIds"])
```

WRONG : Restrictive condition in where clause is before relaxed condition.

```
ultimate_optimized_join = spark_filteredfinal_df1.crossJoin(spark_filteredfinal_df2) \
                        .where( (F.col("df1_a_x_dup") == F.col("df2_a_x_dup"))
                                &
                                (F.col("df1_sorted_row_num") < F.col("df2_sorted_row_num"))
                                ) \
                        .select(["df1_a_x_dup", "df2_a_x_dup", "df1_sorted_row_num", "df1_sorted_row_num",  "df1_collectedIds", "df2_collectedIds"])
```

Answer (score -1):

It should be:

```
$when(((tdata.Age == "" ) & (tdata.Survived == "0")), mean_age_0)
```