# Spark Equivalent of IF Then ELSE

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have seen this question earlier here and I have took lessons from that. However I am not sure why I am getting an error when I feel it should work.

I want to create a new column in existing Spark `DataFrame` by some rules. Here is what I wrote. iris_spark is the data frame with a categorical variable iris_spark with three distinct categories.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

iris_spark_df = iris_spark.withColumn(
    "Class", 
   F.when(iris_spark.iris_class == 'Iris-setosa', 0, F.when(iris_spark.iris_class == 'Iris-versicolor',1)).otherwise(2))
```

Throws the following error.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-157-21818c7dc060> in <module>()
----> 1 iris_spark_df=iris_spark.withColumn("Class",F.when(iris_spark.iris_class=='Iris-setosa',0,F.when(iris_spark.iris_class=='Iris-versicolor',1)))

TypeError: when() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-157-21818c7dc060> in <module>()
----> 1 iris_spark_df=iris_spark.withColumn("Class",F.when(iris_spark.iris_class=='Iris-setosa',0,F.when(iris_spark.iris_class=='Iris-versicolor',1)))

TypeError: when() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 78):

Correct structure is either:

```
(when(col("iris_class") == 'Iris-setosa', 0)
.when(col("iris_class") == 'Iris-versicolor', 1)
.otherwise(2))
```

which is equivalent to

```
CASE 
    WHEN (iris_class = 'Iris-setosa') THEN 0
    WHEN (iris_class = 'Iris-versicolor') THEN 1 
    ELSE 2
END
```

or:

```
(when(col("iris_class") == 'Iris-setosa', 0)
    .otherwise(when(col("iris_class") == 'Iris-versicolor', 1)
        .otherwise(2)))
```

which is equivalent to:

```
CASE WHEN (iris_class = 'Iris-setosa') THEN 0 
     ELSE CASE WHEN (iris_class = 'Iris-versicolor') THEN 1 
               ELSE 2 
          END 
END
```

with general syntax:

```
when(condition, value).when(...)
```

or

```
when(condition, value).otherwise(...)
```

You probably mixed up things with Hive `IF` conditional:

```
IF(condition, if-true, if-false)
```

which can be used only in raw SQL with Hive support.

Comment: Adding slightly more context: you'll need `from pyspark.sql.functions import when` for this.

Comment: When you chain multiple `when` without `otherwise` in between, note that when multiple `when` cases are true, only the first true `when` will be evaluated.

Answer (score 22):

**Conditional statement In Spark**

- Using “**when otherwise**” on DataFrame
- Using “**case when**” on DataFrame
- Using **&&** and **||** operator

---

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{when, _}
import spark.sqlContext.implicits._

val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder().master("local[1]").appName("SparkByExamples.com").getOrCreate()

val data = List(("James ","","Smith","36636","M",60000),
        ("Michael ","Rose","","40288","M",70000),
        ("Robert ","","Williams","42114","",400000),
        ("Maria ","Anne","Jones","39192","F",500000),
        ("Jen","Mary","Brown","","F",0))

val cols = Seq("first_name","middle_name","last_name","dob","gender","salary")
val df = spark.createDataFrame(data).toDF(cols:_*)
```

**1. Using “when otherwise” on DataFrame**

Replace the value of gender with new value

```
val df1 = df.withColumn("new_gender", when(col("gender") === "M","Male")
      .when(col("gender") === "F","Female")
      .otherwise("Unknown"))

val df2 = df.select(col("*"), when(col("gender") === "M","Male")
      .when(col("gender") === "F","Female")
      .otherwise("Unknown").alias("new_gender"))
```

**2. Using “case when” on DataFrame**

```
val df3 = df.withColumn("new_gender",
  expr("case when gender = 'M' then 'Male' " +
                   "when gender = 'F' then 'Female' " +
                   "else 'Unknown' end"))
```

Alternatively,

```
val df4 = df.select(col("*"),
      expr("case when gender = 'M' then 'Male' " +
                       "when gender = 'F' then 'Female' " +
                       "else 'Unknown' end").alias("new_gender"))
```

**3. Using && and || operator**

```
val dataDF = Seq(
      (66, "a", "4"), (67, "a", "0"), (70, "b", "4"), (71, "d", "4"
      )).toDF("id", "code", "amt")
dataDF.withColumn("new_column",
       when(col("code") === "a" || col("code") === "d", "A")
      .when(col("code") === "b" && col("amt") === "4", "B")
      .otherwise("A1"))
      .show()
```

Output:

```
+---+----+---+----------+
| id|code|amt|new_column|
+---+----+---+----------+
| 66|   a|  4|         A|
| 67|   a|  0|         A|
| 70|   b|  4|         B|
| 71|   d|  4|         A|
+---+----+---+----------+
```

Comment: The answer is very nicely detailed, buy OP's tags & question are clearly Python-focused and this answer is done entirely in Scala. Answer could be improved further by noting Python syntax which is often but not always very similar to the Scala equivalent.

Comment: In pyspark && and || operator doesn't exists and it throws SyntaxError. for better understanding refer this link 


 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37707305/pyspark-multiple-conditions-in-when-clause#:~:text=You%20get%20SyntaxError%20error%20exception,doesn't%20consider%20operator%20precedence.

Answer (score 7):

There are different ways you can achieve if-then-else.

1. Using [when](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.when) function in DataFrame API.
   You can specify the list of conditions in when and also can specify otherwise what value you need. You can use this expression in nested form as well.
2. [expr](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.expr) function.
   Using "expr" function you can pass SQL expression in expr. PFB example. Here we are creating new column "quarter" based on month column.

```
cond = """case when month > 9 then 'Q4'
            else case when month > 6 then 'Q3'
                else case when month > 3 then 'Q2'
                    else case when month > 0 then 'Q1'
                        end
                    end
                end
            end as quarter"""

newdf = df.withColumn("quarter", expr(cond))
```

3. [selectExpr](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.selectExpr) function.
   We can also use the variant of select function which can take SQL expression. PFB example.

```
    cond = """case when month > 9 then 'Q4'
                else case when month > 6 then 'Q3'
                    else case when month > 3 then 'Q2'
                        else case when month > 0 then 'Q1'
                            end
                        end
                    end
                end as quarter"""

    newdf = df.selectExpr("*", cond)
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use this:
`if(exp1, exp2, exp3)` inside `spark.sql()`
where exp1 is condition and if true give me exp2, else give me exp3.

now the funny thing with nested if-else is. you need to pass every exp inside

```
brackets {"()"}
else it will raise error.
```

example:

```
if((1>2), (if (2>3), True, False), (False))
```