# Spark dataframe need to check values row wise

Tags: python, apache-spark

I don't have much experience in PySpark

I need to check in Spark Dataframe how many values are greater then certain threshold(absolute) in a row.
I tried this and it doesn't work

```
n = lit(len(df.columns))
rank= (reduce(add, (1 for x in df.columns[1:] if abs(col(x)) > threshold))).alias(rank)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use Python conditionals here. Instead use `when` / `otherwise` ([Spark Equivalent of IF Then ELSE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39048229/9718656)).

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import abs, col, when

reduce(
    add, 
    [when(abs(col(x)) > threshold, 1).otherwise(0) for x in df.columns[1:]])
```