# Pyspark if statement in DF

Tags: if-statement, dataframe, pyspark, variable-assignment

Need help in figuring out how to code this. I have 2 filters to be checked in a Dataframe and assign the values.

```
filters = "LIST_A in {0} AND LIST_B not in {1}".format(include_list,EXCLUDE_list) 

amount = "AND AMT_PD >= 10"

find_df = old_df.if(old_df.format(filters,amount)):
    old_df = old_df.withColumn("ID", F.lit('FOUND'))
            else:
                old_df = old_df.withColumn("ID", F.lit('NOT_FOUND'))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spark Equivalent of IF Then ELSE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39048229/spark-equivalent-of-if-then-else)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if that what you really expect, as you provided example only, but not specified task description:

```
if old_df.filter('{0} {1}'.format(filters, amount)).count() > 0:
  old_df = old_df.withColumn("ID", F.lit('FOUND'))
else:
  old_df = old_df.withColumn("ID", F.lit('NOT_FOUND'))
```

Example above will add another column to data frame with all same values, if at least one record that satisfy conditions found.

Alternatively, if you want to perform check *per record* - query will looks like below:

```
old_df = old_df.withColumn("ID",
                           when(
                               (col('LIST_A').isin(include_list))
                                & ~(col('LIST_B').isin(EXCLUDE_list))
                                & (col('AMT_PD') >= 10),
                               'FOUND'
                           ).otherwise('NOT_FOUND')
```

ID column will be calculated for each record separately based on values in columns LIST_A, LIST_B and AMT_PD for that particular row.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Both ways Worked very well.