# How to create band column based on values pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

I'm newbie into PySpark and I have the following task where I struggle. I have tried few approached, but none of them worked properly. The data is as follows:

```
id|numb_of_count|
1|3|
2|5|
3|6|
4|2|
5|0|
6|15|
7|8|
8|99|
```

I want to achieve the following result:

```
id|numb_of_count|banding|
1|3|3-5|
2|5|3-5| 
3|6|6-10|
4|2|2|
5|0|0|
6|15|+11|
7|8|6-10|
8|99|+11|
```

How this could be possible achieved in the most efficient way, due to I have a large dataset?

Comment: Seems like you want a [series of `if`/`else`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39048475/5858851) statements.

Comment: Hi @pault, could suggest me with an example code?

Comment: You'll have to fill in the logic for the conditions yourself, but you need something like `df.withColumn('banding', when(col('numb_of_count') == 0, "0").when(condition).when(condition).otherwise("+11"))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In pyspark when/otherwise are equivalent of if/else. If `df` is your actual dataframe then:

```
new_df = df.withColumn('banding', when(col('numb_of_count') <3,col('numb_of_count')).when(col('numb_of_count') <=5 , '3-5').when(col('numb_of_count') <= 10, '6-10').otherwise('+11'))
```

#### df.withColumn

`df.withColumn` adds a new column to the frame with first argument as name of new column. more info [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.withColumn)

#### when/otherwise

analogous to if/else, more info [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Column.otherwise)

This is an excellent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39048475/6775799) to learn more about when/otherwise.