# Increment the counter column when encountered a specific value in another column

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe with a column, new_session, that has value either 1 or 0. I want to create another column (session_id) so that increases a counter when the value for the new_session becomes 1.

Sample input:

```
df_tes = spark_session.createDataFrame([
    (1, "item_1"),
    (1, "item_2"),
    (0, "item_3"),
    (0, "item_4"), 
    (1, "item_1")], ["new_session", "item"])
```

```
+-----------+------+
|new_session|  item|
+-----------+------+
|          1|item_1|
|          1|item_2|
|          0|item_3|
|          0|item_4|
|          1|item_1|
+-----------+------+
```

Sample output:

```
+-----------+------+-----------+
|new_session|  item| session_id|
+-----------+------+-----------+
|          1|item_1|   1       |
|          1|item_2|   2       |
|          0|item_3|   2       |
|          0|item_4|   2       |
|          1|item_1|   3       |
+-----------+------+-----------+
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51565395/pyspark-create-new-column-and-fill-in-based-on-conditions-of-two-other-columns Look at this question. Very similar.

Comment: Here's how to implement a cumulative sum column: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45946349/python-spark-cumulative-sum-by-group-using-dataframe

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Create the DataFrame first, note I added two rows with `new_session==2` to demonstrate that the algorithm works with more than two types of `new_session`.

```
df_tes = spark.createDataFrame([
    (1, "item_1"),
    (1, "item_2"),
    (0, "item_3"),
    (2, "item_7"),    
    (0, "item_4"), 
    (2, "item_8"), 
    (1, "item_1")], ["new_session", "item"])
df_tes.show()
```

```
+-----------+------+
|new_session|  item|
+-----------+------+
|          1|item_1|
|          1|item_2|
|          0|item_3|
|          2|item_7|
|          0|item_4|
|          2|item_8|
|          1|item_1|
+-----------+------+
```

2. Prepare the data: we want to know the existing sort order, and generate the correct IDs using rows with `new_session==1`.

```
# Create a `dummy` column so we know the original sort order for the rows. If 
# you already have a column for this, you don't need to create the `dummy` column.

df = df_tes.withColumn('dummy', F.monotonically_increasing_id())

# Create the correct IDs using rows with `new_session == 1`, note we use `dummy` to keep the original order.

df = df.withColumn('id_temp', F.row_number().over(Window.orderBy('dummy').partitionBy('new_session'))).orderBy('dummy')

# Put all rows with new_session != 1 into the same group with 'used == 0'. This 
# helps us to handle cases when there are more than two types of `new_session`. 

df = df.withColumn('used', F.when(F.col('new_session')==1, 1).otherwise(0))
df.show()

+-----------+------+-----------+-------+----+
|new_session|  item|      dummy|id_temp|used|
+-----------+------+-----------+-------+----+
|          1|item_1| 8589934592|      1|   1|
|          1|item_2|17179869184|      2|   1|
|          0|item_3|25769803776|      1|   0|
|          2|item_7|34359738368|      1|   0|
|          0|item_4|42949672960|      2|   0|
|          2|item_8|51539607552|      2|   0|
|          1|item_1|60129542144|      3|   1|
+-----------+------+-----------+-------+----+
```

3. Generate the final `session_id`s.

```
# First, for each row, we use `lag` function to get the `id` from its previous 
# row. So for one row next to a row of `new_session==1`, it'll pick its correct ID here.

w = Window.orderBy("dummy").rowsBetween(-1, -1)
df = df.withColumn('lag_id', F.lag('id_temp', 1, 1).over(w))

# For the rows with `used==0` (i.e. `new_session!=1`), use `first` to apply the 
# correct IDs to all rows.

df = df.withColumn('lag_id', F.first('lag_id').over(Window.partitionBy('used')))

# Now we can use if-else to set the `session_id` properly.

df = df.withColumn('session_id', F.when(F.col('used')==1, F.col('id_temp')).otherwise(F.col('lag_id')))
df.orderBy('dummy').show()

+-----------+------+-----------+-------+----+------+----------+
|new_session|  item|      dummy|id_temp|used|lag_id|session_id|
+-----------+------+-----------+-------+----+------+----------+
|          1|item_1| 8589934592|      1|   1|     1|         1|
|          1|item_2|17179869184|      2|   1|     1|         2|
|          0|item_3|25769803776|      1|   0|     2|         2|
|          2|item_7|34359738368|      1|   0|     2|         2|
|          0|item_4|42949672960|      2|   0|     2|         2|
|          2|item_8|51539607552|      2|   0|     2|         2|
|          1|item_1|60129542144|      3|   1|     1|         3|
+-----------+------+-----------+-------+----+------+----------+
```

You can safely drop the auxiliary columns here, and get the `session_id`.