# How to create a new column based on values of two columns in Spark

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

So, I want to create a new column in my dataframe, whose rows depend upon values from two columns, and also involves a condition.

I tried this, but it doesn't work.

```
some_value = ...
df = df.withColumn("new_col", col("col1") if col("col2") == some_value else None)
```

What is the correct way of doing this?

Comment: you can take a look at `when` and `otherwise` , if that doesnt help , please create a testable example

Comment: or expr is a possibility.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PySpark: Create New Column And Fill In Based on Conditions of Two Other Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51565395/pyspark-create-new-column-and-fill-in-based-on-conditions-of-two-other-columns) What happen to google?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `when` function.

```py
newval='10002'
df2 = df.withColumn("new_col", when((col("col1") == lit(newval)), "col1").otherwise(None))
df2.show()
```

Comment: What do I need to import to use lit?

Comment: Not sure if you imported, you can use `import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._` to use `lit`

Answer (score 0):

A trivial example using with `expr`, can also use `when`:

```
val df3 = df2.withColumn("new_col", expr("case when c1 = 1 and c2 = 101 then c1 + c2 else 999 end"))
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me,

```
 new_col_expr = when(col("col2").eqNullSafe(some_value), col("col1")).otherwise(None)
 df = df.withColumn("new_col", new_col_expr)
```