# How to create a new column for dataset using ".withColumn" with many conditions in Scala Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following input array

```
val bins = (("bin1",1.0,2.0),("bin2",3.0,4.0),("bin3",5.0,6.0))
```

Basically the strings "bin1" refer to values in a reference column on which dataframe is filtered - a new column is created from another column based on boundry conditions in remaining two doubles in the array

```
var number_of_dataframes = bins.length
var ctempdf = spark.createDataFrame(sc.emptyRDD[Row],train_data.schema)
ctempdf = ctempdf.withColumn(colName,col(colName))
val t1 = System.nanoTime
for ( x<- 0 to binputs.length-1)

{
      var tempdf = train_data.filter(col(refCol) === bins(x)._1)
      //println(binputs(x)._1)
      tempdf = tempdf.withColumn(colName,
                                 when(col(colName) < bins(x)._2, bins(x)._2)
                                 when(col(colName) > bins(x)._3, bins(x)._3)
                                 otherwise(col(colName)))
      ctempdf = ctempdf.union(tempdf)
val duration = (System.nanoTime - t1) / 1e9d
println(duration)     
}
```

The code above works incrementally slowly for every increasing value of bins - 
Is there a way I can speed this up drastically - because this code is again nested in another loop.

I have used checkpoint / persist / cache and these are not helping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need for iterative union here. Create a literal `map<string, struct<double, double>>` using [`o.a.s.sql.functions.map`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/lib/permalink.png) (in functional terms it behaves like delayed `string => struct<lower: dobule, upper: double>`)

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val bins: Seq[(String, Double Double)] = Seq(
  ("bin1",1.0,2.0),("bin2",3.0,4.0),("bin3",5.0,6.0))

val binCol = map(bins.map { 
  case (key, lower, upper) => Seq(
    lit(key), 
    struct(lit(lower) as "lower", lit(upper) as "upper")) 
}.flatten: _*)
```

define expressions like these (these are simple lookups in predefined mapping, so `binCol(col(refCol))` is delayed `struct<lower: dobule, upper: double>` and the remaining `apply` takes the `lower` or `upper` field):

```
val lower = binCol(col(refCol))("lower")
val upper =  binCol(col(refCol))("upper")
val c = col(colName)
```

and use `CASE ... WHEN ...` ([Spark Equivalent of IF Then ELSE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39048229/10465355))

```
val result = when(c.between(lower, upper), c)
  .when(c < lower, lower)
  .when(c > upper, upper)
```

select and drop `NULL`s:

```
df
  .withColumn(colName, result)
  // If value is still NULL it means we didn't find refCol key in binCol keys.
  // To mimic .filter(col(refCol) === ...) we drop the rows
  .na.drop(Seq(colName))
```

This solution assumes that there are no `NULL` values in the `colName` at the beginning, but can be easily adjusted to handle cases where this assumption is not satisfied.

If the process is still unclear I'd recommend tracing it step-by-step with literals:

```
spark.range(1).select(binCol as "map").show(false)
```

```
+------------------------------------------------------------+
|map                                                         |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
|[bin1 -> [1.0, 2.0], bin2 -> [3.0, 4.0], bin3 -> [5.0, 6.0]]|
+------------------------------------------------------------+
```

```scala
spark.range(1).select(binCol(lit("bin1")) as "value").show(false)
```

```
+----------+
|value     |
+----------+
|[1.0, 2.0]|
+----------+
```

```scala
spark.range(1).select(binCol(lit("bin1"))("lower") as "value").show
```

```
+-----+
|value|
+-----+
|  1.0|
+-----+
```

and further referring to [Querying Spark SQL DataFrame with complex types](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28332494/10465355).