# Multiple WHEN condition implementation in Pyspark

Tags: t-sql, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, case-when, .when

I've my T-SQL code below which I've converted in Pyspark but is giving me error

```sql
CASE
            WHEN time_on_site.eventaction = 'IN' AND time_on_site.next_action = 'OUT' AND time_on_site.timespent_sec < 72000 THEN 1  --  20 hours 
            WHEN time_on_site.eventaction = 'IN' AND time_on_site.next_action = 'OUT' AND time_on_site.timespent_sec >= 72000 THEN 0
            WHEN time_on_site.eventaction = 'IN' AND time_on_site.next_action = 'IN' AND time_on_site.timespent_sec <= 28800 THEN 2  -- 8 hours
            WHEN time_on_site.eventaction = 'IN' AND time_on_site.next_action = 'IN' AND time_on_site.timespent_sec > 28800 THEN 3
            WHEN time_on_site.type_flag = 'TYPE4' THEN 4
            ELSE NULL
         END AS "type"
```

Below is my Pyspark script which is throwing an error

```sql
from pyspark.sql.functions import when

TOS=TOS.withColumn('type', F.when( (col('eventaction') == 'IN') & (col('next_action') == 'OUT') & ("timespent_sec < 72000") , 1).
                            when( (col('eventaction') == 'IN') & (col('next_action') == 'OUT') & ("timespent_sec >= 72000") , 0).
                            when( (col('eventaction') == 'IN') & (col('next_action') == 'IN') & ("timespent_sec <= 28800") , 2).
                            when( (col('eventaction') == 'IN') & (col('next_action') == 'IN') & ("timespent_sec > 28800") , 3).
                            when(col('type_flag')=='TYPE4', 4).otherwise('NULL')
                            )
```

Where am I going wrong!?

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong with your code. What is the error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spark Equivalent of IF Then ELSE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39048229/spark-equivalent-of-if-then-else)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Nest your 'when' in `otherwise()`. My braces may not be entirely balanced, so do check them, but the idea is the same.

```
TOS=TOS.withColumn('type', F.when( (col('eventaction') == 'IN') & (col('next_action') == 'OUT') & ("timespent_sec < 72000") , 1).
                            otherwise( when(   (col('eventaction') == 'IN') & (col('next_action') == 'OUT') & ("timespent_sec >= 72000") , 0).
                            otherwise( when(   (col('eventaction') == 'IN') & (col('next_action') == 'IN') & ("timespent_sec <= 28800") , 2).
                            otherwise( when(   (col('eventaction') == 'IN') & (col('next_action') == 'IN') & ("timespent_sec > 28800") , 3).
                            otherwise( when(   col('type_flag')=='TYPE4', 4).otherwise('NULL'))))))
```

Comment: Hi @cph_sto i have also this similar issue but in my case i need to update my type table and using my type table in when also.

Comment: Currently my  type column have null values i have 40 sql queries to update this column type each sql queries have 2 conditions.. how can i approach your solution wit my problem

Comment: There is no need for nesting, you can simply chain the `when`s.

Answer (score 9):

I've correctly implemented it as shown below

```
TOS=TOS.withColumn('type', F.when( (F.col("eventaction") == 'IN') & (F.col("next_action") == 'OUT') & (F.col("timespent_sec") < 72000) , 1).
  when( (F.col("eventaction") == 'IN') & (F.col("next_action") == 'OUT') & (F.col("timespent_sec") >= 72000) , 0).
  when( (F.col("eventaction") == 'IN') & (F.col("next_action") == 'IN') & (F.col("timespent_sec") <= 28800) , 2).
  when( (F.col("eventaction") == 'IN') & (F.col("next_action") == 'IN') & (F.col("timespent_sec") > 28800) , 3).
  when(F.col('type_flag')=='TYPE4', 4).otherwise('NULL'))
```