# pyspark join two Dataframe and keep row by the recent date

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have two Dataframes A and B.

A

```python
+---+------+-----+----------+
| id|player|score|      date|
+---+------+-----+----------+
|  1| alpha|    5|2018-02-13|
|  2|  beta|    6|2018-02-13|
+---+------+-----+----------+
```

B

```python
+---+------+-----+----------+
| id|player|score|      date|
+---+------+-----+----------+
|  1| alpha|  100|2019-02-13|
|  2|  beta|    6|2018-02-13|
+---+------+-----+----------+
```

and I must create a new Dataframe where the score is updated by looking the date

result

```python
+---+------+-----+----------+
|id |player|score|date      |
+---+------+-----+----------+
|  1| alpha|  100|2019-02-13|
|  2|  beta|    6|2018-02-13|
+---+------+-----+----------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join the two dataframes, and use [`pyspark.sql.functions.when()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.when) to pick the values for the `score` and `date` columns.

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, when

df_A.alias("a").join(df_B.alias("b"), on=["id", "player"], how="inner")\
    .select(
        "id", 
        "player", 
        when(
            col("b.date") > col("a.date"), 
            col("b.score")
        ).otherwise(col("a.score")).alias("score"),
        when(
            col("b.date") > col("a.date"), 
            col("b.date")
        ).otherwise(col("a.date")).alias("date")
    )\
    .show()
#+---+------+-----+----------+
#| id|player|score|      date|
#+---+------+-----+----------+
#|  1| alpha|  100|2019-02-13|
#|  2|  beta|    6|2018-02-13|
#+---+------+-----+----------+
```

Read more on `when`: [Spark Equivalent of IF Then ELSE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39048229/spark-equivalent-of-if-then-else)

Comment: This will be more efficient than `union`, `distinct`, and grouping.

Answer (score 0):

I am making an assumption that every `player` is allocated an `id` and it doesn't change. OP wants that the resulting dataframe should contain the `score` from the most current `date`.

```
# Creating both the DataFrames.
df_A = sqlContext.createDataFrame([(1,'alpha',5,'2018-02-13'),(2,'beta',6,'2018-02-13')],('id','player','score','date'))
df_A = df_A.withColumn('date',to_date(col('date'), 'yyyy-MM-dd'))

df_B = sqlContext.createDataFrame([(1,'alpha',100,'2019-02-13'),(2,'beta',6,'2018-02-13')],('id','player','score','date'))
df_B = df_B.withColumn('date',to_date(col('date'), 'yyyy-MM-dd'))
```

The idea is to make a [union()](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.union), of these two dataframes and then take the `distinct` rows. The reason behind taking `distinct` rows afterwards is the following - Suppose there was no update for a `player`, then in the `B` dataframe, it's corresponding values will be the same as in dataframe `A`. So, we remove such `duplicates`.

```
# Importing the requisite packages.
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, max
from pyspark.sql import Window
df = df_A.union(df_B).distinct()
df.show()
+---+------+-----+----------+
| id|player|score|      date|
+---+------+-----+----------+
|  1| alpha|    5|2018-02-13|
|  1| alpha|  100|2019-02-13|
|  2|  beta|    6|2018-02-13|
+---+------+-----+----------+
```

Now, as a final step, use [Window()](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/07/15/introducing-window-functions-in-spark-sql.html) function to loop over the unioned dataframe `df` and find the `latestDate` and filter out only those rows where the `date` is same as the `latestDate`. That way, all those rows corresponding to those `players` will be removed where there was an update (manifested by an updated date in dataframe `B`).

```
w = Window.partitionBy('id','player')
df = df.withColumn('latestDate', max('date').over(w))\
       .where(col('date') == col('latestDate')).drop('latestDate')
df.show()
+---+------+-----+----------+
| id|player|score|      date|
+---+------+-----+----------+
|  1| alpha|  100|2019-02-13|
|  2|  beta|    6|2018-02-13|
+---+------+-----+----------+
```