# Replace pyspark column based on other columns

Tags: pandas, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

In my "data" dataframe, I have 2 columns, 'time_stamp' and 'hour'. I want to insert 'hour' column values where 'time_stamp' values is missing. I do not want to create a new column, instead fill missing values in 'time_stamp'

What I'm trying to do is replace this pandas code to pyspark code:

```
data['time_stamp'] = data.apply(lambda x: x['hour'] if pd.isna(x['time_stamp']) else x['time_stamp'], axis=1)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spark Equivalent of IF Then ELSE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39048229/spark-equivalent-of-if-then-else)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f

df = (df.withColumn('time_stamp',
 f.expr('case when time_stamp is null then hour else timestamp'))) #added ) which you mistyped
```

Alternatively, if you don't like sql:

```
df = df.withColumn('time_stamp', f.when(f.col('time_stamp').isNull(),f.col('hour'))).otherwise(f.col('timestamp')) # Please correct the Brackets
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the function "coalesce" which replaces missing values in a given order defined by the index of columns given as function input. In your case the timestamp column would be filled by hour where it is missing.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
data = data.withColumn('time_stamp', F.coalesce('time_stamp', 'hour')
```

Description to the function: https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.coalesce.html

Comment: while the other answer is a more direct translation, this answer is a better practice for this specific use-case.