# Pyspark: I want to manually map the values of one of the columns in my dataframe

Tags: pyspark

I have a dataframe in spark and I want to manually map the values of one of the columns:

```
 Col1
  Y
  N
  N
  Y
  N
  Y
```

I want "Y" to be equal to 1 and "N" to be equal to 0, like this:

```
 Col1
  1
  0
  0
  1
  0
  1
```

I have tried StringIndexer, but it I think it randomly encodes the categorical data. (I am not sure)

The python equivalent for this is:

```
df["Col1"] = df["Col1"].map({"Y": 1, "N": 0})
```

Can you please help me on how can I achieve this in Pyspark?

Comment: StringIndexer will encode based on the descending frequency of the level. Anyways what you want is df.withColumn("Col1", when(df['Col1'] == 'Y', 1). otherwise (0))

Comment: Or you can simply do `df.withColumn("Col1", (df["Col1"]=="Y").cast("int"))`

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to map the values to `1` and `0`, an easy way is to specify a boolean condition and cast the result to `int`

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
df.withColumn("Col1", (col("Col1")=="Y").cast("int"))
```

For a more general case, you can use `pyspark.sql.functions.when` to implement [if-then-else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39048229/spark-equivalent-of-if-then-else) logic:

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import when
df.withColumn("Col1", when(col("Col1").isin(["Y"]), 1).otherwise(0))
```