# how to do intersection of list columns with pyspark dataframe columns?

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

I have a below pyspark dataframe and i need to create new column (new_col) which is common items in column X and Y excluding items in Z.

df

```
id X             Y                    Z            new_col
1 [12,23,1,24]  [13,412,12,23,24]     [12]         [23,24]
2 [1,2,3]       [2,4,5,6]             []           [2]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your schema is the following:

```python
df.printSchema()
#root
# |-- id: long (nullable = true)
# |-- X: array (nullable = true)
# |    |-- element: long (containsNull = true)
# |-- Y: array (nullable = true)
# |    |-- element: long (containsNull = true)
# |-- Z: array (nullable = true)
# |    |-- element: long (containsNull = true)
```

and your pyspark version 2.4+ you can use [`array_intersect`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.array_intersect) and [`array_except`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.array_except):

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import array_except, array_intersect
df=df.withColumn("new_col", array_except(array_intersect("X", "Y"), "Z"))
df.show()
#+---+---------------+---------------------+----+--------+
#|id |X              |Y                    |Z   |new_col |
#+---+---------------+---------------------+----+--------+
#|1  |[12, 23, 1, 24]|[13, 412, 12, 23, 24]|[12]|[23, 24]|
#|2  |[1, 2, 3]      |[2, 4, 5, 6]         |[]  |[2]     |
#+---+---------------+---------------------+----+--------+
```

Comment: thanks pault, is there any way to include X or Y if one of them is null as well and then subtract Z?

Comment: Use [`size`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.size) to check if the array is empty along with [`when`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.when) to do the [pyspark equivalent of if-then-else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39048229/spark-equivalent-of-if-then-else).

Answer (score 0):

You can use withcolumn + udf

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType, ArrayType

def intersection_function(list1, list2):
    intersection_list = [value for value in list1 if value in list2]
    return intersection_list

udf_intersection = F.udf(intersection_function, ArrayType(IntegerType())

newdf = df.withColumn("new_col", udf_intersection(df["ListColumn1"], df["ListColumn2"]))
```

Comment: Yes, look at the answer from @pault