# Pyspark change column value if value from list is in another column

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue

I have a dataframe like so:

```
+-------+----------------+
|Name   |Source          |
+-------+----------------+
|Tom    |clientA-incoming|
|Dick   |clientB-incoming|
|Harry  |c-abc-incoming  |
```

and I would like to add a column `slug` to end up with this dataframe:

```
+-------+----------------+--------+
|Name   |Source          |slug    |
+-------+----------------+--------+
|Tom    |clientA-incoming|clientA |
|Dick   |clientB-incoming|clientB |
|Harry  |c-abc-incoming  |c-abc   |
```

and I have a list of values that have the slugs in them:

`slugs = ['clientA', 'clientB', 'c-abc']`

basically im thinking something along the lines of this pseudocode:

```
for i in slugs:
    if i in df['Source']:
        df['Slug'] = i
```

can someone help me cross the finish line?

EDIT:

I want to update the `slug` column with a value from the `slugs` list. The specific value that goes into the `slug` column is determined based off the `Source` column.

For example, since `slugs[0] = 'clientA'` and clientA is a substring of `clientA-incoming`, I would like to update that row's value in the `slug` column to clientA

Comment: So presumably you'll have some rows that aren't in `slugs` and they're different lengths?

Comment: Do u want to populate `slug`  column based on `Source`  column? or from `slugs` list..?

Comment: every row has a corresponding value in `slugs` but there will be values in `slugs` that dont have a row

Comment: @Shu I want to populate `slug` using data from the list `slugs` based on values from `Source`

Comment: Use a list comp with `coalesce`, `contains`, (or `startswith`) and `when` to do [if-then-else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39048229/spark-equivalent-of-if-then-else) logic: Something like: `df.withColumn('slug', coalesce(*[when(col('Source').contains(slug), lit(slug)) for slug in slugs]))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be solved with a left or inner join depending on your requirements:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import broadcast

slugs = ['clientA', 'clientB', 'c-abc', 'f-gd']
sdf = spark.createDataFrame(slugs, "string").withColumnRenamed("value", "slug")

df = spark.createDataFrame([
  ["Tom", "clientA-incoming"],
  ["Dick", "clientB-incoming"],
  ["Harry", "c-abc-incoming"],
  ["Harry", "c-dgl-incoming"]
], ["Name", "Source"])

df.join(broadcast(sdf), df["Source"].contains(sdf["slug"]), "left").show()

# +-----+----------------+-------+
# | Name|          Source|   slug|
# +-----+----------------+-------+
# |  Tom|clientA-incoming|clientA|
# | Dick|clientB-incoming|clientB|
# |Harry|  c-abc-incoming|  c-abc|
# |Harry|  c-dgl-incoming|   null|
# +-----+----------------+-------+
```

*Note that we broadcast the smaller df to prevent shuffling.*