# How do I set value to 0 of column with multiple statements in Pyspark and Palantir Foundry

Tags: python, pyspark, palantir-foundry

I'm trying to make a statement that basically says if `EDW_ABC.edw_xdpt_act_arrv_lb` is NULL then use `EDW_ABC.edw_putt_act_arrv_lb` and if both are null then set the value to 0. How do I do that? I'm trying the below and I know it's not correct.

```
EDW_ABC = EDW_ABC.withColumn('act_arrv_abc_lbs', F.when(
(EDW_ABC.edw_xdpt_act_arrv_lb.isNull() == True) & (EDW_ABC.edw_putt_act_arrv_lb.isNull() == True). F.lit(0)\
                                         .otherwise(EDW_ABC.edw_xdpt_act_arrv_lb.isNull()), EDW_ABC.edw_putt_act_arrv_lb)
```

Comment: Semi duplicate of, find more details there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39048229/spark-equivalent-of-if-then-else

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spark Equivalent of IF Then ELSE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39048229/spark-equivalent-of-if-then-else)

Answer (score 2):

You will want to use the [pyspark.sql.functions.coalesce()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.coalesce.html) function, which returns the value from the first column in the list that does not return NULL.

```
EDW_ABC = EDW_ABC.withColumn('act_arrv_abc_lbs', F.coalesce(F.col("edw_xdpt_act_arrv_lb"), F.col("edw_putt_act_arrv_lb"), F.lit(0))
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to specify a condition in the `otherwise`, so

```
EDW_ABC = EDW_ABC.withColumn(
    'act_arrv_abc_lbs',
    F.when(
        EDW_ABC.edw_xdpt_act_arrv_lb.isNull() & EDW_ABC.edw_putt_act_arrv_lb.isNull(), F.lit(0)
    ).otherwise(
        EDW_ABC.edw_putt_act_arrv_lb
    )
)
```

`when` and `otherwise` operate as `if` & `else`, so if the first condition in the `when` isn't satisfied, the otherwise automatically assumes the opposite.