# Pyspark Conditional statement

Tags: python, apache-spark, if-statement, pyspark

Below is the input dataframe.

```
+-----------+---------+------------------+----------------------+-----------+
|  DATE    |  ID      |sal               |   vat                |     flag  |
+-----------+---------+------------------+----------------------+------------
|10-may-2022|     1   |             1000.0|                  12.0       1   |
|12-may-2022|     2   |              50.0|                   6.0|       1   |
+-----------+---------+------------------+----------------------+------------
```

I want to perfrom the below based on the flag column

If the flag column is 1, I will do the below.

```
df = srcdf.withColumn("sum",col("sal")*2)
display(df)
```

If the flag column is 2, I will do the below.

```
df = srcdf.withColumn("sum",col("sal")*4)
display(df)
```

Below is the code Im using.

```
flag = srcdf.select(col("flag"))

if flag == 1 :

df = srcdf.withColumn("sum",col("sal")*2)
display(df)

else:
df = srcdf.withColumn("sum",col("sal")*4)
display(df)
```

When I use the above, I am getting syntax error. Is there any other way I can achieve this using the pyspark conditional statements.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39048229/spark-equivalent-of-if-then-else).

You need to use `when` with (or without) `otherwise` from `pyspark.sql.functions`.

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import when, col
df = srcdf\
   .withColumn("sum", when(col("flag") == 1, col("sal") * 2)\
                     .when(col("flag") == 2, col("sal") * 4)
   )
```

OR

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import when, col
df = srcdf\
   .withColumn("sum", when(col("flag") == 1, col("sal") * 2)\
                     .otherwise(col("sal") * 4)
   )
```