# Convert SQL Expression to PySpark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to PySpark. What will be the below sql's PySpark equivalent code ? I understand that I can create a `temp view` and run this sql, however, I am looking for PySpark specific solution.

```
SELECT 
     MAX(CASE WHEN col1 = 'A' THEN 1
              WHEN col2 = 'B' THEN 2
              ELSE 3
         END) AS my_col
FROM mytab
```

How can I represent the above mentioned sql code into PySpark code ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spark Equivalent of IF Then ELSE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39048229/spark-equivalent-of-if-then-else)

Answer (score 2):

I would do it like this

1. test setup

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import when, max, column

spark = (
    SparkSession
    .builder
    .getOrCreate()
)

columns = ["col1","col2"]
data = [("A", "B"), ("C", "B") ,("A", None), (None, "B"), ("B", "A")]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data).toDF(*columns)
```

2. create a new column "my_col_values"

```py
df = df.withColumn(
    "my_col_values", 
    when(df.col1 == "A", 1)
    .when(df.col2 == "B", 2)
    .otherwise(None)
)
df.show()
```

which will result in:

```
+----+----+-------------+                                                       
|col1|col2|my_col_values|
+----+----+-------------+
|   A|   B|            1|
|   C|   B|            2|
|   A|null|            1|
|null|   B|            2|
|   B|   A|         null|
+----+----+-------------+
```

3. select the maximum

```py
df.select(max(df.my_col_values).alias("my_col").show()
```

which will result in

```
+------+
|my_col|
+------+
|     2|
+------+
```

Of course you can do it in one go as well:

```py
df = df.withColumn(
    "my_col_values", 
    when(df.col1 == "A", 1)
    .when(df.col2 == "B", 2)
    .otherwise(None)
).select(max(column("my_col_values")).alias("my_col")).show()
```

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import when, col, max as max_

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("SQLtoPySpark").getOrCreate()

result = mytab.select(
    max_(
        when(col("col1") == 'A', 1)
        .when(col("col2") == 'B', 2)
        .otherwise(3)
    ).alias("my_col")
)

result.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark import SparkContext, SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
import sys
from pyspark.sql.functions import when, max, greatest

sc = SparkContext('local')
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

df = sc.parallelize([
    [1, 'A', 'B'],
    [2, 'B', 'A'],
    [3, 'D', 'C'],
    [4, 'A', 'N'],
    [5, 'N', 'B'],
    [6, 'A', 'A'],
    [6, 'B', 'B']
]).toDF('id: integer, col1: string, col2: string')
df.show(20, False)

df = df.withColumn("my_col", when(df.col1 == 'A', 1).when(df.col2 == 'B', 2).otherwise(3))
df.show(20, False)

df_answer = df.select(max(col("my_col")))
df_answer.show(20, False)
```

Outputs:

```
+---+----+----+
|id |col1|col2|
+---+----+----+
|1  |A   |B   |
|2  |B   |A   |
|3  |D   |C   |
|4  |A   |N   |
|5  |N   |B   |
|6  |A   |A   |
|6  |B   |B   |
+---+----+----+

+---+----+----+------+
|id |col1|col2|my_col|
+---+----+----+------+
|1  |A   |B   |1     |
|2  |B   |A   |3     |
|3  |D   |C   |3     |
|4  |A   |N   |1     |
|5  |N   |B   |2     |
|6  |A   |A   |1     |
|6  |B   |B   |2     |
+---+----+----+------+

+-----------+
|max(my_col)|
+-----------+
|3          |
+-----------+
```