# Multiple condition filter on dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Can anyone explain to me why I am getting different results for these 2 expressions ? I am trying to filter between 2 dates:

```
df.filter("act_date <='2017-04-01'" and "act_date >='2016-10-01'")\
  .select("col1","col2").distinct().count()
```

Result : 37M

vs

```
df.filter("act_date <='2017-04-01'").filter("act_date >='2016-10-01'")\
  .select("col1","col2").distinct().count()
```

Result: 25M

How are they different ? It seems to me like they should produce the same result

Answer (score 61, accepted):

**TL;DR** To pass multiple conditions to `filter` or `where` use `Column` objects and logical operators (`&`, `|`, `~`). See [Pyspark: multiple conditions in when clause](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37707305/1560062).

```
df.filter((col("act_date") >= "2016-10-01") & (col("act_date") <= "2017-04-01"))
```

You can also use **a single** SQL string:

```
df.filter("act_date >='2016-10-01' AND act_date <='2017-04-01'")
```

In practice it makes more sense to use between:

```
df.filter(col("act_date").between("2016-10-01", "2017-04-01"))
df.filter("act_date BETWEEN '2016-10-01' AND '2017-04-01'")
```

The first approach is not even remote valid. In Python, `and` returns:

- The last element if all expressions are "truthy".
- The first "falsey" element otherwise.

As a result

```
"act_date <='2017-04-01'" and "act_date >='2016-10-01'"
```

is evaluated to (any non-empty string is truthy):

```
"act_date >='2016-10-01'"
```

Answer (score 1):

In first case

```
df.filter("act_date <='2017-04-01'" and "act_date >='2016-10-01'")\
  .select("col1","col2").distinct().count()
```

the result is values more than 2016-10-01 that means all the values above 2017-04-01 also.

Whereas in second case

```
df.filter("act_date <='2017-04-01'").filter("act_date >='2016-10-01'")\
  .select("col1","col2").distinct().count()
```

the result is the values between 2016-10-01 to 2017-04-01.

Comment: I get this error when adding multiple conditions to the filter Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o355.or. Trace:
py4j.Py4JException: Method or([class java.lang.String]) does not exist