PySpark: multiple & | conditions in when clause
I would like to add multiple conditions to the when function, and it is returning the py4jError.

Code:

df.withColumn('column1', when(condition1 & condition2 & (condition3 | condition4), df.column1+1).otherwise(df.column1))

Error:

`Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o6974.and. Trace:     py4j.Py4JException: Method and([class java.lang.Boolean]) does not exist     at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:321)     at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:329)     at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:274)     at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)     at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)     at
py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)     at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)`
I have validated all the conditions and their data types.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/56973584/3238085  Note:In pyspark, it is important to enclose every expressions within parenthesis () that combine to form the condition
